# Crashing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I am making a webview browser that uses sliding menu fragments. When I open this fragment then the app crashes. I am new to fragments so I apologize if this is nooby. If there's anything else I can do to help with this then just ask.

Below is the fragment class

```
public class WhatsHotFragment extends Fragment {

public WhatsHotFragment(){}

WebView WebViewB;
ProgressBar Pbar6;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, container, false);

    Pbar6 = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progBar6);
    WebViewB = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.wvBrowserAesir);

    WebSettings webSettings = WebViewB.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebViewB.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    WebViewB.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    WebViewB.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    WebViewB.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    WebViewB.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient());
    WebViewB.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
           {
           if(progress < 100 && Pbar6.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.VISIBLE){
               Pbar6.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
           }
           Pbar6.setProgress(progress);
           if(progress == 100) {
               Pbar6.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
           }
           }
       });
        {
            WebViewB.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }


    return rootView;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
  Pbar6 = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progBar6);
  WebViewB = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wvBrowserAesir);
```

You can also use `getView().findViewById` in `onActivityCreated` to initialize your views.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! It was rootView not rotoView :) Thanks again.

Comment: @Tssomas i understand its the site rules.